# Video tearing on flash fullscreen

Tags: nvidia, video, flash, tearing

I had some trouble with video tearing (using Nvidia GeForce 560Ti, with 310.44 nvidia driver), but could solve it by setting refresh rate from 50 to 120 in compiz settings manager -> composite.
However, tearing is still a problem when watching flash videos. For example, the following video shows heavy tearing in fullscreen: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=22ftfoCSPQI

When watching it using totem and vlc I have no tearing at all (I downloaded the video).

As suggested in many different other posts about this topic, I enabled VSync in compiz and nvidia-settings. Additionally, I enabled "prefer maximum performance" in nvidia-settings. Both without any effect.

I'm currently using chrome 27.0.1453.93 with flash plugin "Shockwave Flash 11.7 r700" on a ubuntu 13.04 64Bit machine.

Any suggestions, how to minimize tearing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've searched and found [this](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=160454) it does have some workarounds like **enabling** the setting "**Override software rendering list**" in **chrome://flags/** some say it works but it's not guaranteed may be worth a try.

Comment: Better but still with some tears.